# How to best iterate through Request.Form and matching Session key

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I best iterate through Request.Form and match a Session key? I'm building a shopping cart.

I have a unique id as a Session key, and a whole number for the value of that key. When a Form key's value gets updated, I want the session value to update too.

Let's say we originally set Session.Contents["id-101"] = 1, then my page sends a form with Request.Form["id-101"] = 4; I want Session.Contents to update the Value to 4.

This doesn't work because I'm not accessing the value of the form item, I think...

```
foreach (string item in Request.Form) 
{
  if (item == Session.Contents[item])
  {
     Session.Contents[item] == Request.Form[item];
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: When your  page sends a form with Request.Form["id-101"] = 4; you need to update that session

Comment: I don't know the key name when I'm iterating. That's why I'm not sure how to accomplish this...

Comment: loop all available sessions, find the session key ("id-101") and update that session which is holding that key

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: I may have up to 5000 possible product codes, so that's why I'm saying I want to see if the Session key matches the Request.Form key.  The Request.Form's may be 'id-101' with the value being the quantity value, like 4..

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do that

```
List<int> listValues = new List<int>();
foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    if (key.StartsWith("List"))
    {
        listValues.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[key]));
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work -- putting the keys into a list seems pretty heavy-handed.  There must be a simpler way to do this.